# How do you get total sum of a column for a specified date?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a where the index column are dates. The other columns are total sales for each product for a specific day. I need to get total sales for each column for the year 2010.

I know how to get the total sum of a column, but I am having problem in getting the sum for a specific data/time frame.

The dates on index column come in the following format `2007-09-22`

Comment: please add the code snippet that you have done so far for the above task

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected output? Be free change `rng = pd.date_range('2018-04-03', periods=10, freq='4M')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product 1': range(10), 'Product 2': range(1, 11)}, rng)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your index pretty flexibly if it is a date-time index.
If using the the dataframe (as provided by @jezrael), you can do the following.

`df.groupby(df.index.month).sum()`

**Output**

```
    Product 1   Product 2
4   18          22
8   12          15
12  15          18
```

Or

`df.groupby(df.index.year).sum()`

**Output**

```
       Product 1    Product 2
2018    3           6
2019    12          15
2020    21          24
2021    9           10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [partial string indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing) with `sum`:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2018-04-03', periods=10, freq='4M')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product 1': range(10), 'Product 2': range(1, 11)}, rng)  
print (df)
            Product 1  Product 2
2018-04-30          0          1
2018-08-31          1          2
2018-12-31          2          3
2019-04-30          3          4
2019-08-31          4          5
2019-12-31          5          6
2020-04-30          6          7
2020-08-31          7          8
2020-12-31          8          9
2021-04-30          9         10
```

---

```
print (df['2020'])
            Product 1  Product 2
2020-04-30          6          7
2020-08-31          7          8
2020-12-31          8          9
```

If need sum per rows:

```
print (df['2020'].sum(axis=1))
2020-04-30    13
2020-08-31    15
2020-12-31    17
Freq: 4M, dtype: int64
```

If need sum per columns:

```
print (df['2020'].sum())
Product 1    21
Product 2    24
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple groupby can work for aggregates. If you want to aggregate using multiple columns, look it up in [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for groupby using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': ['2007-09-22', '2007-09-23','2007-09-22'], 'Product 1': [1,2,3], 'Product 2': [4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Date','Product 1','Product 2'])

df.groupby('Date').sum()
```